# How to set font size for a textbox in RDLC using parameter in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rdlc

I am using a title for report that I want to be changed by user at run time specially the font face and font size the face is changing well at run time but the size does not I tried so many ways but I am stuck. if somebody help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Font Size is read only, you can't change it at run time.

You need to find an other solution: create multiple textboxes with different font.size and you show the one you want for example.

Hope this help!
Adrien

Comment: Thanks any way, but the problem was that I was not putting "Pt" after the size value in the expression as I put, that worked.

Comment: =Parameters!fontSizeParameter.Value + "Pt"